# Combine code and math mode

Tags: math-mode, code

So i want to insert some line of codes in a formula like in the picture below. What is the best way to do this properly? [image]

Comment: Will this be in an equation? Will it be part of a code segment? What is the main/underlying structure? My guess is its the latter (like an `lstlisting`).

Comment: This should be an equation.I have tried something like \text{some code} in the mathmode but then the code is not structured well.

Comment: Can you show us the used [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to produce this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a replication of the display inside an equation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\newcommand{\var}{\texttt}
\newcommand{\AND}{\wedge}

\newcommand{\curlylbrace}{\texttt{\symbol{123}}} % \{
\newcommand{\curlyrbrace}{\texttt{\symbol{125}}} % \}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{array}{ l }
    \bigl( \var{max} \doteq 0 
      \AND \var{i} \doteq 0 
      \AND \var{i} < \var{a.length} \rightarrow
        \begin{array}[t]{ @{} l }
          [ \curlylbrace
          \begin{tabular}[t]{ >{\ttfamily}l }
            if(a[i] > max) max = a[i]; \\
            i++; \\
            while(i < a.length) \curlylbrace \\
            \quad if(a[i] > max) max = a[i]; \\
            \quad i++; \\
            \curlyrbrace
          \end{tabular} \\
        \curlyrbrace ] \psi_0)
      \end{array} \\
    {} \AND (\var{max} \doteq 0
      \AND \var{i} \doteq 0
      \AND \var{i} \geq \var{a.length} \rightarrow [ \curlylbrace \curlyrbrace ] \psi_0 \bigr)
  \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```